# No SqlParameter.UdtTypeName on netcoreapp1.1! How to use UDT?

Tags: .net-core, user-defined-types, sqlparameter

This UdtTypeName property is required to read or write Geography, Geometry or HierarchyId.
I can't find any workaround or post/information on this subject.
Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not implementend in netcoreapp1.1.

There is an issue about that in the dotnet corefx project, referencing all the missing API of System.Data.SqlClient, and especially about UdtTypeName: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17126