# .Net Core: can't pass "geography" parameter to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to pass a parameter of SQL Server type `geography` to a stored procedure from .Net Core.

So far, I have installed the `System.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Spatial` packages. Here is my code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myproc", connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // Here, GeographyPoint is of type Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPoint, and
    // I am pretty sure this is the wrong type to use...
    GeographyPoint gp = GeographyPoint.Create(lat, lon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", gp);

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When I try to execute this, I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type Microsoft.Spatial.GeographyPointImplementation to a known managed provider native type

Then I tried to install the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` package, but it is not compatible with .Net Core 1.1:

> Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)

Then I tried to specify that the geography parameter is Udt:

```
cmd.Parameters["@Location"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt; 
//cmd.Parameters["@Location"].UdtTypeName = "Geography";
```

**HOWEVER**: I can't set the `UdtTypeName` to `Geography` because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315760/no-sqlparameter-udttypename-on-netcoreapp1-1-how-to-use-udt?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), so this won't work because the `UdtTypeName` is required for Udt parameters.

Then, I upgraded to .Net Core 2.0. I tried adding the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package again: this time it installed "successfully", but when I build my project, I get this error:

> warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.314.76' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I can't access any of the types in my code, so that didn't work.

And the question remains: how do you pass a parameter of SQL Server type `geography` to a stored procedure from .Net Core?

Comment: Disclaimer: I've done this 5+ years ago... but can you pass a string in the form of `"(lat,lng)"` as a param and see if that works?

Comment: I tried several variations of a formatted string, but no luck: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type nvarchar to geography.

Comment: as a workaround maybe you can try to change the SP to accept 2 floats and combine that to a geography point in the SP

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I am hoping for a proper solution in .Net Core first. I am planning on passing various geometry types for this parameter (not just points), and I don't want to create a stored proc for each one.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Good point - thanks!